# How to count the number of records in cross-reference field in RSA Archer GRC?

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

I need to create a `numeric` field that would calculate the number of records in a `cross-reference` field. My version of RSA Archer GRC is 6.5.

As I understd, there isn't any standard function for this type of calculations. At least I can't find it. I can use `Data Feed` for this task, but calculated field is much better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alexander you can use `COUNTA([Cross-reference Field])` and that will return the number of cross-reference numbers linked to the record

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply count the number of records in a cross-reference, related record or a sub-form, use the COUNTA function, either in a calculated text or a numeric field:

```
COUNTA([Cross Reference Field])
```